# How can i execute .asp as .php in MAMP PRO?

Tags: php, macos, mamp, mamp-pro

I want MAMP PRO to execute .asp files as .php. I dont have any htacess there, but i edited http.conf file.

I have already added a line on httpd.conf, like this `AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp .aspx` but it still shows the PHP source code.

It won't execute them either, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a line...

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp .aspx
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .asp .aspx
```

Remember to restart MAMP.